# How to display the answer in upper case?

Tags: c++

I can't find the mistake. The program input:

```
1
21 London 22:00
London
```

And output should be:

```
21_LONDON_22:00
```

But the program gave me:

```
21_L_22:00
```

Here is my code, so where is the mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include<ctype.h>
using namespace std;

struct train {
    int ID;
    string destination;
    string time;
};

int main(){
    train tr[1000]; // train - datatype, tr - variable
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin >> tr[i].ID;        
        cin >> tr[i].destination;
        cin >> tr[i].time;
    }
    string location;
    cin >> location; //LONDON
    bool found = false;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        //upper_case(location) == upper(tr[i].destination)
        location=toupper(location.at(i));
        tr[i].destination=toupper(tr[i].destination.at(i));
        if (location.at(i)==tr[i].destination.at(i)){
            cout << tr[i].ID << "_" <<tr[i].destination.at(i)<< "_" << tr[i].time <<endl;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found == false)
        cout << "Impossible";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I vote to close as a typo because you asked for the 1st character of the string but probably didn't mean to, so the program is doing exactly what you asked.

Comment: `location=toupper(location.at(i));` replaces the entire location with the first letter capitalized. The next i becomes then interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You are using : `cout ... << tr[i].destination.at(i)`, try `cout ... <<tr[i].destination` instead

`tr[i].destination.at(i)` will output the i-th character in the string `tr[i].destination`.

In this case, `i == 0`, `tr[0] == London`, thus the output will be `L`, the first (at position 0) character in the string `LONDON` instead of the whole string: `LONDON`

Also, your check stops if the first character of `location` and `destination` match, i'm not sure it's the intended behaviour.

If you want to perform the check on the whole `tr[i].destination`, you should use the [compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) function in your `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Using C++11 and toupper(), I used

```cpp
for (auto & c: str) c = toupper(c);
```

to convert your string to uppercases.

With this method, I adapted your code and...it works

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include<ctype.h>
using namespace std;

struct train {
    int ID;
    string destination;
    string time;
};

int main(){
    train tr[1000]; // train - datatype, tr - variable
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin >> tr[i].ID;        
        cin >> tr[i].destination;
        cin >> tr[i].time;
    }
    string location;
    cin >> location; //LONDON
    bool found = false;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        //upper_case(location) == upper(tr[i].destination)
        for (auto & c: location) c = toupper(c);
        for (auto & c: tr[i].destination) c = toupper(c);
        if (location.at(i)==tr[i].destination.at(i)){
            cout << tr[i].ID << "_" <<tr[i].destination<< "_" << tr[i].time <<endl;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found == false)
        cout << "Impossible";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: toupper(int) transforms one character from lower to upper. The operation has to be repeated for transforming a string.